# Android How to set pixels on camera preview

Tags: android, camera

Is there is any way to set pixels on cameraPreview, [like getting pixel](http://www.41post.com/3470/programming/android-retrieving-the-camera-preview-as-a-pixel-array) or some other ways?
**My requirement:**  I want to put some pixels on a particular positions on camera preview or convert some pixel value of some points in camera preview into another value.

Comment: Well, I have done little try on it. But its not a good prectise. see this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981159/how-it-is-to-set-this-colour-pixel-effect-in-android-camera-preview

Comment: I have made the green transperent layer above the camera Preview. Thats why it looks like the Night Vision as per my Above answer. Please See my above question. but again its not a Good Prectise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by placing a custom view in front of the surface view, on each `PreviewCallback` I draw an image and set it as background of that custom view. It feels drawing pixels on camera preview. `I dont know this is the actual method, if I get optimal solution I will update here` 
 
Custom view

```
public class DrawOnTop  extends View {

public DrawOnTop(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}}
```

Create camera activity implements `PreviewCallback`
To set custom view infront of surfaceview

```
DrawOnTop mDraw = new DrawOnTop(this);
    addContentView(mDraw, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

In `onPreviewFrame` you can do code for creating image according to preview display and set that image as background of the custom view.

```
@Override  
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {  
    //your code
}
```

Comment: i also want to do like this but i dont understand well your answers please you describe me your answers ?,where to put that all and all?

Comment: i want to open camera with green color camera preview on activity start.